# Saving method for Rich Text editor

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I found a great tutorial on making a nice rich text editor at the address below

http://ios-blog.co.uk/featured-posts/ios-5-rich-text-editing-series/

However, if i want to build an app. I want this can be saved and loaded anytime i want to edit it. My question is what is the best saving method for this kind of text editing application? plist? core data? How can i do that?

Thanks